# Determine if $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ is a group under usual product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm doing an exercise about determining if some sets with binary operations have group structures. I'm struggling with this one:

> The set $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, with the usual product.

What I've done (I'm not sure if the following is correct):

The elements of $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ are $\{[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11]\}$, this are the elements of that set (and this is independently of what operation are you considering).

You have $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, so the elements are $\{[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11]\}$.

A friend of mine said I have to consider only the elements $[1],[5],[7],[11]$. I don't understand why we can ignore the other elements of the set and whether what he said is correct.

Any hint is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is $[6] \cdot [6]$? Is $[6]$ invertible then? Is the set closed under multiplication at all?

Comment: Please look at my edits.  You'll see how to write $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ in MathJax, and you can also use that code in LaTeX. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I didn't know how to write it properly. Thank you very much Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you are proving is not true. On the other hand $(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})^\times$ or $(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})^*$ which is defined as what your friend said (ie the numbers which are coprime to $12$) is indeed a group with respect to multiplication.

If you don't see it now try to prove why the first set cannot form a group!

Comment: My first try was: $[3]\cdot[4]=[0]\not\in G$, with $G$ the set defined in my question, so the binary operation is not closed, and it can't be a group. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Also no inverse for those element etc

Comment: Jack, thank you very much for your time!